# Coloring Triangulation from Set of Points

Tags: matlab, plot, triangulation

I have a matrix with n rows and 4 columns. The first 3 columns indicate the x,y,z position of a point. The last column indicates a colour value, 'p', for that point.

Is there any way to plot the triangulation of these points with the colour of the surface of each triangle defined by 'p'? Or perhaps the colour defined by the average of the 'p' values that went into creating that particular triangular surface?

I've tried a few of the options from the documentation, to no avail.

**My attempt:**

```
interiorPoints = [matrix(:,1),matrix(:,2),matrix(:,3)];
DT = DelaunayTri(interiorPoints); 
hullFacets = convexHull(DT);
c=matrix(:,4);
trisurf(hullFacets,DT.X(:,1),DT.X(:,2),DT.X(:,3),c)
```

But I get an error:

> Warning: Error creating or updating Patch
>
> Error in value of property  FaceVertexCData
>
> Number of colors must equal number of vertices or faces

Comment: What kind of "bit of a trouble"? [`trisurf`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/trisurf.html) and friends seem straightforward. Another option might be to interpolate your data on a regular mesh and use `pcolor` or `surf`.

Comment: Hi @AndrasDeak, I've added the code I'm trying a well as the error in the original question. Not sure how to get the colour matrix to be done.

Comment: @VladislavMartin How does this work? When I attempt to run the code snippet you wrote, it gives me an error: 

Error: The input character is not valid in MATLAB statements or expressions.

Comment: @VladislavMartin Ahh, fixed that issue. But the question remains how does this get applied to the mesh I generate using trisurf?

Comment: I must have had a typo in my previous comment: `colormap_index = fix((matrix(:,4)-min(matrix(:,4)))/(max(matrix(:,4))-min(matrix(:,4)))*length(matrix(:,4)))+1`. As for how you apply the colormap, that is simple: `trisurf(...)` (don't use the `c` though) and, next line, `colormap(colormap_index)` should do the trick.

Comment: When you try to map `c=matrix(:,4)` on a point-by-point basis to the triangulation you created, that probably won't work. You see, `c` is supposed to color every face on your triangular surface. You'll need to make `c` as large as the `Triangulation` vector that is produced by `DelaunayTri(interiorPoints)`. This vector will almost never be the same size as the number of points you used to form the triangulation, so you'll need to map the color separate by means of an index (as I explained), or create a list of meaningful color values from the triangulation data returned from `DelaunayTri`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Why the `trisurf(x,y,z,c)` approach isn't working

You can't use the `trisurf(x,y,z,c)` approach because `c` has to be the same length as your `Triangulation` matrix, which it won't be. This is because you won't generate **the same number** of triangular faces from your matrix as you have points in your matrix.

It's worth mention that it's not recommended (says so in [the documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/delaunaytri.html)) that you use MATLAB `DelaunayTri()` function. Instead, you should use MATLAB's [`delaunayTriangulation()` function](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/delaunaytriangulation-class.html).

### A Working Approach to Coloring Triangular Surfaces

Below, I have detailed / commented a block of code that will color the triangular surfaces drawn from your `interiorPoints` variable according to the color values stored in the 4th column of your `matrix` variable.

In this code, I have mapped the color values to varying shades of blue and I have mapped the color values to MATLAB's `jet` color map. If you would like, you could create 5th and 6th columns in your `matrix` variable so that you can specify the `R`, `G`, and `B` color components for more vibrant color mappings:

```
interiorPoints = [matrix(:,1),matrix(:,2),matrix(:,3)];
c=matrix(:,4);

% MATLAB recommends that you use delaunayTriangle...
% DT = DelaunayTri(interiorPoints); 

DT = delaunayTriangulation(x,y,z)
hullFacets = convexHull(DT)

% Create an empty RGB colormap
custom_cm = zeros(length(c),3);
% Or, instead of creating an empty color map, you could modify one of MATLAB's available color maps
modify_cm = colormap(jet) % Replace 'jet' with any other of MATLAB's available color maps 

% "B" is the 3rd component of this RGB color map
custom_cm(:,3) = ((c-min(c))/(max(c)-min(c))*length(c)) / length(c)

% Expand the scaled custom_cm column for multiplication with the original color matrix
cm_multiplier = repmat(custom_cm(:,3), 1, 3);
% Multiply element-wise the expanded custom_cm with the original color matrix
modify_cm = cm_multiplier.*modify_cm;

trisurf(hullFacets, DT.Points(:,1), DT.Points(:,2), DT.Points(:,3))

% Use the entirely custom color mapping
colormap(custom_cm)

% Or, use the modified color mapping
colormap(modify_cm)
```

I don't have the data stored in your `matrix` variable, so I triangulated some sample data and colored it according to a random set of data I generated as a 4th column. Here's how it came out looking using the entirely custom color map:

[image: Sample plot of Delaunay triangulation, colored according to custom color map]

Here's how it came out looking using the modified `jet` color map:
[image: Sample plot of Delaunay triangulation, colored according to modified <code>jet</code> color map]

I hope this helps, happy coding!

Comment: This is great! Is there any way to set the colormap to be of the typical ones available in MATLAB, i.e. 'jet', 'hsv' etc.

Comment: Sure, editing my answer right now to illustrate how that would be done.

Comment: Awesome! :D Thanks Vladislav